# while loop with counter down line

Tags: bash, awk

I have a list of urls in text file as following

```
https://example.com/test.php?x=1
https://example.com/test.php?x=1&y=2
```

and i`m doing while loop while executing certain command on those lines as following

```
while read line ;
        do command ;
done < list.txt
```

i need to print on the terminal a counter down in the loop function so i can know the estimated time to end of list or another word to know the rest of lines to the end of list.

i have tried `awk -v x="$url" '$0~x {print NR}` but did not work out

Comment: If you reference `line` in `command`, use double quotes: `"$line"`, because you might have characters like `&`in `$line` that have special meaning to `bash`.

Comment: btw, you don't need to end lines with `;`.

Comment: not sure I understand what you mean by `print ... counter down in loop`; do you mean something like `processing URL #3 of 10 ...` (where `10` is the number of URLs/lines in `list.txt`)? or do you mean something else? it would help if you provide a few lines of the expected output as URLs are being processed in your `while` loop

Comment: @markp-fuso yes the desired output will be ```processing URL #3 of 10``` which 10 is the number of lines in file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sample input:

```
$ cat list.txt
https://example.com/test.php?x=1
https://example.com/test.php?x=1&y=2
https://example.com/test.php?x=1&y=3
https://example.com/test.php?x=1&y=4
https://example.com/test.php?x=1&y=5
https://example.com/test.php?x=1&y=6
https://example.com/test.php?x=1&y=7
```

One idea:

```
urlcount=$(wc -l < list.txt)
loopcount=0

while read -r url
do
    ((loopcount++))
    echo "Processing URL #${loopcount} (of ${urlcount}) [ ${url} ] ..."

    sleep 3     # replace with 'command ...'

done < list.txt

echo "Done."
```

Which generates the following output (lines printed @ 3 second intervals):

```
Processing URL #1 (of 7) [ https://example.com/test.php?x=1 ] ...
Processing URL #2 (of 7) [ https://example.com/test.php?x=1&y=2 ] ...
Processing URL #3 (of 7) [ https://example.com/test.php?x=1&y=3 ] ...
Processing URL #4 (of 7) [ https://example.com/test.php?x=1&y=4 ] ...
Processing URL #5 (of 7) [ https://example.com/test.php?x=1&y=5 ] ...
Processing URL #6 (of 7) [ https://example.com/test.php?x=1&y=6 ] ...
Processing URL #7 (of 7) [ https://example.com/test.php?x=1&y=7 ] ...
Done.
```

Comment: thanks this worked for me plus i added ```echo -e "\nProcessing URL #${loopcount} (of ${urlcount}) [ ${url} ]\n"

Comment: sure, that works, too :-)  for extra formatting (eg, `\n`) I tend to use `printf` as `echo [-e]` isn't always implemented the same across various unix/linux envs, ymmv ...

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

readarray -t urls < "${@:--}"

for i in "${!urls[@]}"; do
    printf '%d/%d URL: %s\n' "$((i+1))" "${#urls[@]}" "${urls[i]}"
done
```

```
$ ./tst.sh file
1/4 URL: https://example.com/test.php?x=1
2/4 URL: https://example.com/test.php?x=1&y=2
3/4 URL: https://example.com/test.php?x=1&y=3
4/4 URL: https://example.com/test.php?x=1&y=4
```